# Problem creating a lstnewenvironment that starts/ends another environment

Tags: latex, beamer

I am currently using Beamer and the listing package to pretty-print code into Beamer blocks. So what I'm doing looks like :

```
\begin{block}{}
\begin{lstlisting}
int foobar(void) { return 0; }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
```

Now, I find it cumbersome to start the `block` and `lstlisting` environments everytime. I'd like to have a simple `codeblock` environment that just does it:

```
\begin{codeblock}
int foobar(void) { return 0; }
\end{codeblock}
```

So, I tried something like :

```
\lstnewenvironment{codeblock}
{\begin{block}{}}
{\end{block}}
```

But unfortunately, the Beamer document no longer compiles, with the following error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.178 \end{frame}

?
```

Is there some way to do this ?

In [Problem with creating a newenvironment in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606794/problem-with-creating-a-newenvironment-in-latex), Andreas Grech had the same problem, but it could solve it since there was another way to enter/exit the enclosing environment. But in the case of the `block` Beamer environment, it seems there is no other way than doing `\begin{block}...\end{block}`.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?

Comment: For the record, there is the same problem with `\begin{tabular}{...}` and `\end{tabular}`, but problem is solved using the TeX style `\tabular{...}` and `\endtabular`. I have no idea why (I thought both forms were strictly equivalent). Unfortunately, this does not seem to be applicable to beamer's `block` environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not find a solution for it. My workaround was to use the \lstinputlisting command and have the code in a separate file. That's great if you have real code you want to include. Not so for small examples.

Another workaround is to put the code snipplet into a variable before starting the {frame} environment and then reference it. How to do this is explained in latex-beamer docs. It would also allow you to employ your custom environment/command.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by using the `fancyvrb` package's `\VerbatimOut`(See [write environmnet body verbatim to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/write-environment-body-verbatim-to-a-file)) to create a temporary file which then can be included with `lstinputlisting`:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{blocklisting}[1]
{\begingroup\lstset{#1}\VerbatimOut{blocklisting-tmp.txt}}
{\endVerbatimOut\begin{block}{Code}\lstinputlisting{blocklisting-tmp.txt}\end{block}\endgroup}
```

For some reason i could not make the environment-argument optional, though.

Used like this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Whatever}
\begin{blocklisting}{language=Java, basicstyle=\Huge}
Code
\end{blocklisting}

\begin{blocklisting}{}
Code 2
\end{blocklisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Not the optimal solution, but it works, i guess.