# Using listings package in macro

Tags: macros, latex, listings

I'm creating a latex document that will describe various C++ syscall functions. I need to include their prototypes, descriptions, return values, and common uses. I've been told that to include code, I need to use the `listings` package, but I am using code within sentences and tables, so the commands for listings gets crowded and unreadable.

[image: my latex shot]
The first table without bold characters and titles for the columns.

Here's my code.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\begin{lstlisting} 
void perror(const char* s) 
\end{lstlisting} 
&
\begin{lstlisting} 
stdio.h, errno.h 
\end{lstlisting}
\\
& prints argument message \begin{lstlisting} 
s 
\end{lstlisting}
\ based on global int 
\begin{lstlisting}
errno
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
```

The code looks really messy and is difficult to read. I tried to fix this with a macro but it did not work. I'm programming in shareLatex right now.

```
\newcommand{\lstcode}[1]{
\begin{lstlisting} 
#1
\end{lstlisting} }
```

I like the idea of simply using backticks for code in the middle of sentences. Even individually, the perror is bulky as code and I'd love to make the table look more like a table in my code too. How do I:

include code in a way that doesn't clutter up my table? (`perror`'s declaration)

include code in the middle of a sentence? (`s` and `errno`)

Answer (score 1):

[Problem with creating a newenvironment in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606794/problem-with-creating-a-newenvironment-in-latex/2606830#2606830)

Macros have, thankfully, been created before for lstlisting and require that a special environment is made for them.

```
\lstnewenvironment 
 {⟨name⟩}[⟨number⟩][⟨opt. default arg.⟩]
 {\lstset{label=#1}}
 {⟨ending code⟩}
```

EDIT: After trying this, I couldn't use it. I switched to \texttt{} instead for its easiness of use. Any other choices would be cool, but for now this is good.